# Emacs: Universal argument (C-u) in a function

Tags: function, emacs, arguments

I would like to use <kbd>C-u</kbd> in a function (for instance, regexp) where calling it with <kbd>C-u</kbd> has a different effect. How can I do this in Emacs? The documentation doesn't show how to do this with Emacs Lisp.

```
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (align-regexp)) ; I would like to add the C-u prefix to this.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
(defun my/test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg 4)) ;; emulate C-u
    (call-interactively 'align-regexp) ;; invoke align-regexp interactively
    )
  )
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent. Does what it has to and with some explanation.

Comment: Note that the necessary argument value to emulate `C-u` *varies*, depending on the expectations of the original function (i.e. its argument to `interactive`). If it accepts a "raw" prefix argument, then you would want to pass the list `'(4)` rather than the numeric value `4`. See `C-h i g` `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments` `RET`

Comment: I don't understand, it seems this is not the poster asking for. I think it should be: do one thing if not called with C-u, and do another thing once called with C-u.

Comment: Thanks, I used this with org-journal to suppress the automatic time-entry creation.

Comment: If you don't want to pass any arguments to the function, instead of 4, you can use `(current-prefix-arg '-)`

Answer (score 18):

I arrived here looking for a way to detect if *my* function had been called with C-u. This is how you do it:

```lisp
(defun my-function ()
 (interactive)
  (if (equal current-prefix-arg nil) ; no C-u
   ;; then
    (message "my-function was called normally")
   ;; else
    (message "my-function was called with C-u")))
```

What the original poster was asking is how to call *another* function with C-u, *from inside his/her function*. 
I post this as a clarification to @codyChan's comment above, in the hope that it might help others.

Comment: Me too, thanks it did. If you swap your branches you can use `(if current-prefix-arg ...` instead

Comment: This is also the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Not the answer PascalVKooten wanted, but the answer we all needed.